# Symbolizing a line feature based on polygon location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology

using 10.2.2 desktop to be imported as a service on to AGOL

I am looking for a way to change symbology of my line features, water mains, based on a polygon, pressure zone. Field operations would like to see the color of water mains change as it flows through different pressure zones. I was hoping for a way where I could symbolize water mains to match the color of the known pressure zone without cutting up my line feature classes per polygon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this without cutting up the lines (e.g. intersect with the polygons) since each line can only have one symbol. If it is just for visualisation why not copy the dataset and split that one leaving the topologically correct version for analysis?